# Firebase AppCheck is not working for angularJS, showing 100% Unverified requests for Realtime Database

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

Firebase AppCheck is not working for angularJS, Showing 100% Unverified requests for Realtime Database

**Firebasejs: 3.6.4**

**Angularfire: 2.3.0**

**AngularJS: 1.6.0**

I have modified the Firebasejs library to add header **'X-Firebase-AppCheck'** but after that storage is showing as 100% verified request but Realtime Databse is still showing 100% unverified request.

```
<script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-app.js'
    import { initializeAppCheck, getToken, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-app-check.js"

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXX.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://XXXX.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "XXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXX.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXX",
        appId: "1:CXXX:web:XXX"
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app,
    {
        provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider("XXXXXX")
    })

    var appCheckToket;
    try {
        appCheckToket = await getToken(appCheck,false);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    token = appCheckToket.token;
</script>
```

Re-captcha assessment for login action

```
grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
            let recaptchaToken = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('XXXXX', {action: 'LOGIN'});
            var data ={
                "event": {
                    "token": recaptchaToken,
                    "siteKey": "XXX",
                    "expectedAction": "LOGIN"
                }
            };
            $http({method: 'POST',
                    url:"https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/projects/leaderbord-552b1/assessments?key=AIzaSyA1-mY-XXXXX",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
                .then(function (success) {
                    console.log(success);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
            });
            
        });
```

Not sure we have to upgrade my application to Angular 16 because I have an application with Angular 16 and not getting this issue.